# How come that an Android app can be built without repositories in buildscript?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to understand what repositories does in buildscript. I have read quite a few posts explaining it, but I still feel that I have not grasped the concept. Here is the project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
//    repositories {
//        jcenter()
//        maven {
//            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
//            name 'Google'
//        }
//    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
 }


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

You can see that I have commented out repositories in buildscript.  The app is built perfectly, and published without any problems.  Could anyone shed some light on this?  Maybe an example showing repositories in buildscript is required will help me understand it finally.

Comment: Did you clean the cache before commenting these lines? Because if you have the plugin cached before it works in any case

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti  Per your commented, I did the following: File > Invalidate Caches/Restart..., then built and ran the debug version, built the release version that uses Proguard.  No problem so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error, Android Studio provides the plugins or at least sources of the plugins itself while compiling and building even if the `repositories` block was commented out. This is most probably due to the fact of it's high integration with Gradle. However when building from the command line using `gradlew assembleDebug` or something similar, the Gradle wrapper will throw the following error:

> "Cannot resolve external dependency
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 because no repositories are
>   defined."

As to further explain the concepts for clarity, the `repositories` under `buildscript` defines the sources of downloading the plugins used in compiling your Gradle project. For example the Android Gradle Plugin is downloaded by defining the repo that contains it (Google maven in this case) and adding the dependency `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1` for the buildscript. Hence by doing that, you'll be able to add the plugin with `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` inside your app module `build.gradle` file. This is not yet related to your code libraries, this is just related to the build system in order to compile the project Projects by using plugins which have tools and extra tasks to compile them properly.

If you realize below the `buildscript` block, there is the `allprojects` block which states the repositories used in order to handle project dependencies. Meaning the libraries that your are using in your app (which are also inside the `dependencies` block in app `build.gradle` file) are retrieved from there and in this case they are from JCenter, JitPack.io and Google Maven.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help.  I waited till the end of the week to test your suggestion to minimize the risk of interrupting the normal tasks.  I closed AS, deleted directory .gradle, started AS, built and ran the project.  The app works flawlessly.  It is really puzzling.  I do make sure the repositories block is commented out in build.gradle.

Comment: Are there other `build.gradle` files within the project that contain a `repositories` block?

Comment: I could also suggest to try compiling the project from the command line. Probably AS has extra handling for such scenarios. Running `gradlew assemble` from within the project root directory will compile the code and create the apk in `build/outputs` of ur app module

Comment: I have realized that I did not make it clear that I primarily wanted to understand how gradle works within Android Studio. I get the following "Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 because no repositories are defined.
" when run gradlew assemble.

Comment: Sorry for the late are reply. The error that you got is what I think ur looking for. So based on the details that we have, Android Studio most likely handles the case of not declaring repositories and provides them itself when using it. However when compiling and building from the command line using `gradlew`, it does check for the repositories of the plugins that are applied and tries to get them based on what's declared in the `repositories` block in `build.gradle`. Since they're commented out, Gradle couldn't find from where it should get the plugins and hence threw this error. Ans updated.

Comment: After AS was upgraded 3.1 two days ago,  the error "Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 because no repositories are defined" showed up immediately.  I had to restore the commented out block to make it work again.

Comment: Yeah this seems to be the expected behavior so that's a gd thing